# Ask the user to provide paths to non-python files to my library

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

EDIT: I rewrote and shortened the question because it seemed unclear!

I am currently writing a python program, and some of the functionalities are improved if it has access to some specific, non-python files. (I am talking about datasets here)

The problem is that **I don't have the right to share those files myself**, and also that they are very big, which is not practical for sharing them along with my library.

The user has two possibilities:

- Using the program stand-alone, with only basic features
- Download the files by requesting them to the owner(s), then use advance features

In that second case, I would like to know what is the best practice for asking the user "If you have these files on your machine, tell me where so I can use advanced functionalities from now on". 
I can see several ways to achieve this but none of them seemed very clean or pythonic (e.g. Ask the user to copy files at a specific place within the library, or ask the user to write the paths in a config file, etc...).

What is the *good* way of doing this? Or at least, is there a standard way?

Answer (score 0):

Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to handle different conventions and make path os independent. Usually, I tend to keep my paths in separate file, like `config/paths.py`. Always use relative paths.

```
from pathlib import Path


class Paths:
    A: Path = Path('data/foo.csv')
    B: Path = Path('data/foo2.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is a bit different. I just want a way for the user to tell the library: "Yes I have downloaded this dataset, and it is _there_ on my machine". After that, I can use `pathlib` or `os.path` to access files within the dataset.